# Looping through a file and calculate logarithm and exponential function

Tags: linux, bash, awk, logarithm, exp

I have a simple text file containing some negative values:

*sample.txt*

```
-61.68
-69.00
-90.93
-95.25
```

Need to calculate following mathematical operation:

```
result1 = exp(ln(10)* -61.68/10)
result2 = exp(ln(10)* -69.00/10) + exp(ln(10)* -90.93/10) + exp(ln(10)* -95.25/10)
result = result1/result2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you transpose the values, i.e. put them on one line, before handing them over to `awk`, it becomes a simple transcription, e.g.:

*calc.awk*

```
{
  print \
    exp(log(10) * $1/10) /\
    (\
           exp(log(10) * $2/10) \
         + exp(log(10) * $3/10) \
         + exp(log(10) * $4/10) \
    )
}
```

Run it like this:

```
<sample.txt paste -s | awk -f calc.awk
```

Output:

```
5.34813
```

Note that `log()` in awk takes the natural logarithm.